# [R]: conditionally delete entire row from Excel sheet on basis of a column value

Tags: python, r

i have a excel file contain two sheet.
sheet 1 is

```
    Col.1  Col.2  Col.3 Col.4 Col.5 Col.6 Col.7 Col.8
1      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
2      6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
3     11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
4     16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23
5     21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28
6     26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33
7     31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38
8     36    37    38    39    40    41    42    43
9     41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
10    46    47    48    49    50    51    52    53
```

and Sheet 2 contains

```
starInterval      endInterval
1                   10
51                  70
21                  30
```

now i want to select first row from Sheet 2 and search in col.8 in sheet 1 for If values found between 1 and 10 delete entire row and then select 2 row in sheet 2 and continue.

the code in R i have written is

```
File1 = loadWorkbook("exp.xlsx")  # read file
IntervalSheet = readWorksheet(File1, sheet =  2) #read sheet 2
File1.Rows = nrow(IntervalSheet)




StartInterval = IntervalSheet[,1]
EndInterval = IntervalSheet[,2]


#read sheet 1 in which we have to delete the rows 
MalwareSheet = readWorksheet(File1, sheet =  1)
Malware.Sheet.Rows = nrow(MalwareSheet)




for (i in 1:File1.Rows )
    {
        # value selection from interval sheet
        startvalue = StartInterval[i]
        endvalue = EndInterval[i]

        for (j in 1:Malware.Sheet.Rows)
            {

                 d<-MalwareSheet[!(MalwareSheet$col.8 >= startvalue & MalwareSheet$col.8 <= endvalue),]
                    print (d)
                j= j+1
            }
        i = i+1
    }
d
```

it returns me ......

```
[1] Col.1 Col.2 Col.3 Col.4 Col.5 Col.6 Col.7 Col.8
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

but i am expecting output

```
        Col.1  Col.2  Col.3 Col.4 Col.5 Col.6 Col.7 Col.8

    2      6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
    3     11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    6     26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33
    7     31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38
    8     36    37    38    39    40    41    42    43
    9     41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
```

This is a sample sheet i have a large data approximately 21000 rows are there thats why i want to do it with help of programming. If it is possible in python then also suggest me

Comment: You just asked this question few days ago!

Comment: @Osdorp but i did not get solution yet. So that is why i have posted once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R`, we loop through the sequence of rows of the second dataset, remove the rows if the 'Col.8' values are in the sequence of values from 'starInterval' to 'endInterval' for each row of the second data, and update the first dataset

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2))) {

   df1 <- df1[!(df1$Col.8 %in% seq(df2$starInterval[i], df2$endInterval[i], by = 1)),]
  }

df1
#     Col.1 Col.2 Col.3 Col.4 Col.5 Col.6 Col.7 Col.8
#2     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
#3    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
#6    26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33
#7    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38
#8    36    37    38    39    40    41    42    43
#9    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
```

where 'df1 and 'df2' are the first and second sheet of the excel data read using  either `readxl` or `XLConnect` or one of the packages

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col.1 = c(1L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 36L, 
41L, 46L), Col.2 = c(2L, 7L, 12L, 17L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 
47L), Col.3 = c(3L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L
), Col.4 = c(4L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 29L, 34L, 39L, 44L, 49L), 
    Col.5 = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L
    ), Col.6 = c(6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 36L, 41L, 46L, 
    51L), Col.7 = c(7L, 12L, 17L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 47L, 
    52L), Col.8 = c(8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L, 
    53L)), .Names = c("Col.1", "Col.2", "Col.3", "Col.4", "Col.5", 
"Col.6", "Col.7", "Col.8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df2 <- structure(list(starInterval = c(1L, 51L, 21L), endInterval = c(10L, 
70L, 30L)), .Names = c("starInterval", "endInterval"), class = "data.frame",
        row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: it giving error

`Error in seq.default(df2$starInterval[i], df2$endInterval[i], by = 1) : 
  'from' must be of length 1`

Comment: @sanjay.sharma  For me, it is working fine with the data I showed in my post

Comment: please if dont mind please explain me **for** loop how its working

Comment: @sanjay.sharma  Sure,  If you notice that I am assigning the original object to a subset on each loop `df1 <- df1[.`.  So after each run, the object gets updated based on whether the rows are removed or not and you get the final output of the updated object